# Use Ctrl+Tab/Ctrl+Shift+Tab to cycle through open tabs in Guake

Tags: guake

I would like to cycle through open tabs in Guake the same way I do in Chromium or Firefox with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. But for some reason Guake Config won't let me.

If I go to "Guake Preferences" > "Keyboard Shortcuts" there are the two options:

- Go to previous tab
- Go to next tab

But the GUI won't let me assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to them.

Answer (score 0):

The developers of Guake have accepted this as a feature, but have not yet implemented it. https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/152

Apparently there are some challenges since gtk doesn't allow the tab key to be used as an accelerator, but supposedly there are ways around that.